# Monitoring usage amount for each user in Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a central Amazon AWS account and 87 users. As I figured out, there is no way to allocate credit to each single user (like $40 of the whole credit on the account).

Please let me know if there is a way to figure out current usage of each user from the total credit. For example have list showing user no. 1 has user $3 so far and no. 2 has used $40 ...

Users have access to EC2, ERM and S3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks friends I found the solution with your help.
Using consolidated billing we are able to see to total usage amount and separately for each user.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're already using [consolidated billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html), but it might serve as a solution

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.
It's mentioned that we can get a list of costs. Does it contain usage amount for each single user? And Can we have the cost list when ever we want or it will be available everyone month? Because we want to de-link each user who exceeds $40 and we need to see the usage amount for each user every day.

Comment: I can't be a 100 percent sure. You would probably have to contact support because I personally don't use consolidated billing.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is [cost allocation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/getbill.html#allocation).

> You can use cost allocation to organize and track your AWS costs. When you apply tags to your AWS resources (such as Amazon EC2 instances or Amazon S3 buckets), AWS generates a Cost Allocation Report as a comma-separated value (CSV) file with your usage and costs aggregated by your tags. You can apply tags that represent your business dimensions (such as cost centers, application names, or owners) to organize your costs across multiple services.

When you follow the steps to activate this feature, you specify an S3 bucket where the reports will be dropped.  There's a final report at the end of every billing cyle but there are also "estimated" rolling reports that get dropped into the bucket several times a day.

Answer (score 0):

Cost allocation reports from AWS definitely help. But it can be tough to turn all that CSV data into reports, especially if you've got a lot of individual users.

A lot of tools have been built to help with this issue. It's one that a lot of AWS users run into.

This blog post gives some hints on how to create more useful allocation reports: http://blog.cloudability.com/insight-with-aws-cost-allocation-reports/

As a disclaimer, I work at Cloudability. We've got a lot of users with this exact same issue.